# Remove ms from epoch time retrieved with json.loads

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a pipe separated file with one field containing some information in JSON format:

```
1|2|{"StartTime":1572300507000,"EndTime":1547506800474,"DeleteTime":1572217199000}|4
```

In order to retrieve the JSON values I'm using json.loads.

Bellow is a part of my code:

```
import sys,json,time


with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        fields = line.split('|')
        print time.strftime('"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"', time.localtime(json.loads(fields[2])['StartTime'])
```

Which doesn't work as expected, since the epoch time has also ms. The simpliest solution would be to devide the epoch with 1000 and do something like this:

```
time.strftime('"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"', time.localtime(json.loads(fields[2])['StartTime']/1000)
```

Which of course doesn't work since I'm getting the following error:

> ```
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'time.struct_time' and 'int'
> ```

Which is the proper way to do this? I'm trying to find also the most efficient way since the file has million of rows.

Comment: 1. Parentheses are mismatched. Please show where one missing closing parenthesis is. (It is missing in both original code and in the code with division). 2. The error shows the time is already a struct_time, suggesting that missing parens is before the `/1000`? If yes, move it after.

Comment: Seems like a mismacthed parantheses as @h4z3 pointed out `time.strftime('"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"',  (time.localtime(json.loads(fields[2])['StartTime']/1000))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should divide the number, your error is based on mismatched parentheses:

```
d = '''{"StartTime":1572300507000,"EndTime":1547506800474,"DeleteTime":1572217199000}'''
time.strftime('"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"', time.localtime(json.loads(d)['StartTime']/1000))
```

Output:

```
'"20191028230827"'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Maurice.. I would swear that i tried this multiple times..